# Returning String array in a function with void return type

Tags: java, compiler-errors, bluej

I am getting continuous errors about the above matter. Please help.....
I have to submit this code as a part of my project by next Friday. I have seen other programs on the internet but they all use buffer reader so I cant understand.

```
void sports()
{
    
    String word, clue;
    
    <code related to initialization of word and clue>

    return String {word,clue};
}
```

}

Comment: @Simze why? That's totally fine. The problem is the return statement at the very end of the last method.

Comment: @Ansh your method ``sports`` has the return type of void, meaning you can't return anything. Yet that's what you try here: ``return String {word,clue};``. Also that statement is not a valid expression.

Comment: Sorry my bad! Deleted comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Change your function

```
void sports() {

    // Code 

        return String {word,clue};
    }
```

To:

```
String[] sports() {

        // Code 
        return new String[]{word, clue};
    }
```

it Means you just have to change your return type of function sports and return a valid object.